# Login with email instead of username in web api Oath

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, oauth, asp.net-identity

I'm using token based authentication in web api to login use.

As It default format to login a user using username

```
grant_type=password&username=admin@gmail.com&password=12345678&client_id=AndroidApp
```

and `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

But I want to login with email. so I created a new class inheriting `OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext`

```
public class CustomeOAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext : OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public CustomeOAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext(IOwinContext context, OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions options, string clientId, string userName, string password, IList<string> scope, string email)
            :base(context, options,clientId,userName,password,scope)
        {
            this.Email = email;
        }
    }
```

change the method `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials`
from

```
 public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
           //some code 
        }
```

to

```
 public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(CustomeOAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
           //some code 
        }
```

So that when I pass the data like this

```
grant_type=password&email=admin@gmail.com&password=12345678&client_id=AndroidApp
```

But In this case It show me compile time error `CustomeOAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext` does not have suitable method to override.

Comment: What's the matter on using `grant_type=password&username=admin@gmail.com&password=12345678&client_id=AndroidApp`, with email address in the username field?

Answer (score 0):

This error is shown because the method GrantResourceOwnerCredentials() in the class ApplicationOAuthProvider is the overridden method which is oresent in the class OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider. So, you cannot use CustomeOAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext type as parameter.

If you are using UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password) to create users, then you need to use username for the verification - ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

If you just need to pass email, then
One solution is you can use the scope to pass in the emailid. eg.grant_type=password&Username1=Admin&Password=Admin@1&Scope=a@b.com

Answer (score 0):

Too late but may helpful for new developers.
Don't need to change anything like creating new class and overriding, just navigate to

```
Provider/ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs
```

and change the method like below

```
ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(context.UserName);
```

make sure you're passing email in UserName field, then check if the user is not null, if null return context error like below.

```
if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }
```

if user is not null, check password which is supplied with the  userManager.CheckPasswordAsync function like below.

```
var isOkay = await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, context.Password);
            if (!isOkay)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }
```

if isOkay returns true, that's mean the email and password combination is okay and proceed next to generate auth token.

The whole code will be like below.

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
            var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(context.UserName);
            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }
            var isOkay = await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, context.Password);
            if (!isOkay)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }

            ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
               OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
            AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
            context.Validated(ticket);
            context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
        }
```